# create transaction in c# for executing series of function calls (all or none)

Tags: c#, transactions

i want to implement a transaction in my code which is separated by functions.
There is one function in which all other functions are called. I want to make this function execute the function calls in a transaction (All or None).
Some of the function calls are queries while some are routine code for C# and Crystal report.
Can Some one help with this?

This function is working perfectly.
But if 2 users are accessing same database and executing this function at same time may get Cuncurrency problem.

### the function code is attached.

public bool Generate_PDF(decimal wo_id)
{

```
        if (Fill_WO_Report_Table(wo_id) == false)   // this function has queries
            return false;

        try
        {
            string exception;
            cryRpt = new ReportDocument();

            cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\CrRpt_WO_Report.rpt");
            DB_Interface.CrystalReport_Login(ref cryRpt, out exception);

            string Temp_file_path = @"c:\Reports\WO_Temp.pdf";
            cryRpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Temp_file_path);

            string File_name = str_WO_File_Name + ".pdf";
            // option to print at which location
            //DialogResult dlg = MessageBox.Show("Select Option For Print :\n\nYes - Print To Default Path\nNo - Print To Custom Path\nCancel - Do Not Print",
            //                                        "Print GRN", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            SaveToDialog frm = new SaveToDialog(ref File_name);
            DialogResult dlg = frm.ShowDialog();
            File_name = frm.GetString();
            frm.Dispose();
            frm = null;

            if (dlg == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(MMS_Vars.PathReport_WO) == "")
                    throw new Exception("Default Path Not Available.");

                string Full_File_name = Convert.ToString(MMS_Vars.PathReport_WO) + "\\" + File_name;
                cryRpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Full_File_name);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Full_File_name);
            }
            else if (dlg == DialogResult.No)
            {
                SaveFileDialog obj_saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                obj_saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Convert.ToString(MMS_Vars.PathReport_WO);
                //obj_saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
                obj_saveFileDialog.FileName = File_name;    //set file name to 
                obj_saveFileDialog.Filter = "PDF Files|*.pdf";

                DialogResult result = obj_saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK && obj_saveFileDialog.FileName != "")
                {
                    cryRpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, obj_saveFileDialog.FileName);
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(obj_saveFileDialog.FileName);
                }
                else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    obj_saveFileDialog.Dispose();
                    cryRpt.Close();
                    cryRpt.Dispose();
                    return false;
                }
                obj_saveFileDialog.Dispose();
            }
            else if (dlg == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                cryRpt.Close();
                cryRpt.Dispose();
                return false;
            }
            cryRpt.Close();
            cryRpt.Dispose();

            // Drop Report tables
            if (Drop_WO_Report_Table() == false)    // this function has queries
                return false;

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exe)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exe.Message, "WO Report", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted any of the functions you do on your db. Are there any writes, etc? From your posted code, adding a transaction will probably not solve your problem. A simple solution can be to add a lock around the function so only one pdf is created at a time:

```
 private static object locker = new object();

 public bool Generate_PDF(decimal wo_id)
 {
      lock(locker){
        if (Fill_WO_Report_Table(wo_id) == false)   // this function has queries
            return false;
            ........
            ........
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exe)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exe.Message, "WO Report", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }
      }//END LOCK
    }
```

Comment: the queries are in the function calls, Fill_WO_Report_Table(wo_id), and , Drop_WO_Report_Table()

Comment: and by the way only one pdf gets generated by executing this code.

Comment: If you have only one web server and Fill_WO_Report_Table(wo_id), and , Drop_WO_Report_Table() are only called from this function. The lock construction will do what you want.

Comment: i have 2 users executing this function from 2 different PCs at the same time on a single server, Client-Server type, n-Clients and 1-server. will this lock work here?

Comment: I guess the code is running on the webserver, so you should be fine.

Comment: no its a desktop application running on n-independent Computers all connected to one server.

Comment: what happens if its a windows app ?

Comment: The lock works only local. You can do lock via the db. I've a code sample on this machine...